Next.js with capacitor js
I am trying to create an e-commerce site with next.js. I want to use this application as a mobile app with capacitor.js. But there is a problem. When I add a new product or create a new category, my mobile application does not update. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Right now we cannot give you a good answer. Please update the question to include a text-based [mre]
